# All Google App script custom functions yield #ERROR

Tags: google-apps-script

Google Scripts no longer works for me.

Example 1: Drag down a fun "hello world" function and you'll see a bunch of #ERROR.

Example 2: Drag down a function that makes a URLFetch and you'll see all #ERROR.

If I run a custom function in one cell, it's likely to work. But as soon as I drag, #ERROR.

See example spreadsheet and script: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1vZl8Z6xC5BUcN6MI9FcwGXGPTkbt4QNllT5Eoj27PtI/edit?usp=sharing

Anyone from Google can help?

Comment: See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401759/apps-script-custom-function-internal-error), which is a duplicate. An issue has been raised on the tracker.