# Google Sheets App Script: Internal error executing the custom function

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, internal-server-error, custom-function

I have a custom function that periodically will return the error: `Internal error executing the custom function.` The custom function execution lasts `0 (zero) seconds` according to the executions page on the App Script website.
[image]

I have contact Google multiple times about this insisting that it is a platform error, but I get the same answer every time - "Add a random delay in your function" or "Use exponential backoff". I have tried adding a random delay and this did help slightly, but the error was still there - just less occurrences. I currently have exponential backoff implemented for all App Script APIs and even with this retry logic I get the same error.

I've followed the entirety of the App Script documentation for best practices including using ranges, and even with this the error is still there.

Is anyone else experiencing this? I tried adding a `Logger.log` on the very first line of my custom function and this code does not trigger when I receive this error. This leads me to believe that the custom function calls just never reach the server where the code executes. This is why I believe it's a platform error.

This is the exponential backoff code:

```
function call_(func) {
    for (var n = 0; n < 6; n++) {
        try {
            return func()
        } catch (e) {
            Logger.log(`Retrying... ${n + 1} times exception: ${e}`)
            if (n === 6 - 1) {
                throw e
            }
            Utilities.sleep(
                Math.pow(2, n) * 1000 + Math.round(Math.random() * 1000)
            )
        }
    }
}
```

This is a condensed version of the custom function:

```
function CUSTOMFUNCTION() {
    let apiResponse = call_(() =>
            UrlFetchApp.fetch(someUrl, {
                muteHttpExceptions: true,
            })
        )

      let response = JSON.parse(call_(() => apiResponse.getContentText()))
    // do some logic with the response
    return value

}
```

I'm aware that http exception won't be caught and this is intentional. While testing the custom function in the development sheet that the script is attached to, I can't reproduce the error no matter what I try. The error only ever happens after the script is deployed via Google Cloud Platform (GCP). For clarity, inside GCP I use the Google Workspace Marketplace SDK to attach the script ID in order to make the add-on available to anyone to add to their Google Sheets.

If anyone has any input to help with resolving this error I would appreciate it as the Google team hasn't been very helpful over the past few months of triaging this issue.

Comment: Can I ask you about the detail of `The error only ever happens after the script is deployed via Cloud Platform.`?

Comment: Are there global variables or any loading code outside the function?

Comment: @Tanaike I've updated the question to better explain why I use GCP

Comment: @TheMaster I do have global variables and global functions in the script such as the call_ function shown above. What issue could global variables cause?

Comment: Other than functions, are there any global code that's immediately executing? They load before custom function is called and therefore maybe responsible for such unknown errors.

Comment: @TheMaster No, there isn't any code executing immediately that could cause issues. It is only constants and helper functions declared.

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding more information. Although I had tried to replicate your situation, unfortunately, I cannot still replicate your situation. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for my poor skill. In your situation, even when your custom function is put to one cell, such an error occurs? Or, your custom function is put to multiple cells? First, I would like to correctly replicate your situation.

Comment: @Tanaike it only occurs when there are a lot of cells using the same function. I would say in the range of 25-50 cells

Comment: Thank you for replying. I deeply apologize for my poor skill, again. Unfortunately, I cannot still understand your situation. When I could correctly replicate your situation, I would like to think of the reason for it and a solution. I would be grateful if you can forgive my poor skill.

Comment: Have you tried looking at the [GCP logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs-explorer-interface) to see if there is more information contained there? If the problem occurs only when your use this function a lot - it is very likely the hit some quota limits, for example the maximum number of URL fetch calls per day - see [Current quotas](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/quotas#current_quotas).  Also, this post is a bit old, but might help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31401759/apps-script-custom-function-internal-error

Comment: @ziganotschka I've looked through all the logs and monitored the executions directly in the App Script project and I don't see any trace of quota error's since I've implemented caches to combat this. I've tried just about everything recommended on here and nothing has worked.

Comment: Does it help though to reduce the frequency of your requests? O redesign your functionality in such a way that you don't use so many custom formulas / update them so often? Did you file an issue on Issue Tracker that is currently being worked on?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue ended up being caused by our overall script size.

After reaching out to google we were informed that on each custom function request Google will retrieve the entire contents of your App Script code. Not just the code/file used for custom functions. The upper limit on their download size is 5mb.

Because of this, we changed our webpack configuration resulting in a much smaller bundle size (<1mb). Google also created a file cache to speed up this process on larger App Script projects.

Hopefully this'll help someone else who runs into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

API Limits.
https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/limits

implement exponential backoff, solved the issue for us.

```
async function myFunction(params) {
  let result = -1

  for (let i = 0; i<10; i++){
    try {
      let response = await UrlFetchApp.fetch("MY URL");
      result = await response.getContentText()
      if (result >= 0) {return result}
    } catch(err) {
      await setTimeout(r, 1000*i);
    }
  }
  return err.message
}
```

Then we also set the sheet to auto-refresh formulas
https://spreadsheetpoint.com/auto-refresh-google-sheets/
(might not be related)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This is more or less what we already had - I ended up figuring out the issue and it was due to something else which I'll answer to this question shortly.